# how to fix findOneAndUpdate?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have a very simple query and update using mongoose that is not working.

```
router.get("/logout", auth, (req, res) => {
console.log(req.user.email)
User.findOneAndUpdate({ email:req.user.email}, { token: "", tokenExp: "" }, (err, doc) => {
    if (err) return res.json({ success: false, err });
    return res.status(200).send({
        success: true
    });
});
});
```

All it's supposed to do is delete current (String) in token and current (Number) in tokenExp. However I am getting this error in Postman after trying to run:

```
{
"success": false,
"err": {
    "operationTime": "6907973176379047937",
    "ok": 0,
    "code": 9,
    "codeName": "FailedToParse",
    "$clusterTime": {
        "clusterTime": "6907973176379047937",
        "signature": {
            "hash": "QLS3kLG+OJKY1pUZwHLz/5YzexA=",
            "keyId": "6876394347730829315"
        }
    },
    "name": "MongoError"
}
}
```

What am I doing wrong? I've also included useFindAndModify: false.

Answer (score 1):

Well according to your question you are trying the delete current (String) in token and current (Number) in tokenExp but you are assigning a string to token so it is giving an error.

Try this as the unset operator deletes a particular field. When used with $ to match an array element, $unset replaces the matching element with null rather than removing the matching element from the array. This behavior keeps consistent with the array size and element positions.Also, you can use just the update query of MongoDB with unset.

```js
router.get("/logout", auth, (req, res) => {
   console.log(req.user.email)
   User.findOneAndUpdate({ email:req.user.email}, { $unset:{ token: "", tokenExp: "" }}, (err, doc) => {
      if (err) return res.json({ success: false, err });
      return res.status(200).send({
         success: true
      });
   });
});
```

Comment: Tried and I am still getting the same error, I have notice that I can use findOne successfully to query and return data. Any time I try to to save or modify thats when I seem to get the error.

Answer (score 0):

You may be defined `tokenExp` as `Number`. But now you are trying to assign an empty string into `tokenExp`. So, mongo can not parse the string into numbers and thus the error.

Solution: Try to use [unset](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/unset/).